# Terms for grandparents and other relatives

Tags: american-english, kinship-terms, dialects, variants, informal-writing

I’m a teenager from the Midwest. Different people obviously refer to their relatives in many different ways, and I’ve noticed a wide variance in what people call their grandparents.

Many people who are fortunate enough to have three our four living grandparents seem to use some sort of affectionate name for one grandparent, but not for the corresponding one on the other side of the family. For example, when my mother tells stories about her grandparents, one grandmother is always “Grammie” and the other is “Grandma” (or “Gramma,” if you want to spell how it’s actually pronounced (or [ˈɡɹ̈æ̝̃ˌmɒ̽], if you want to spell how it’s ACTUALLY pronounced)). There are seemingly an extreme number of possibilities, like “nana,” “papa,” “gran,” “granny,” and “gramps.”

I assume this is many people’s experience, maybe even most, but it is not mine. My sister and I have always referred to our paternal grandparents as “Grandma ⟨our last name⟩” and “Grandpa ⟨our last name⟩,” and our maternal grandparents, similarly, as “Grandma ⟨our mom’s last name⟩” and “Grandpa ⟨our mom’s last name⟩.” Although this feels normal to me, I have realized that it sounds very strange to some people. I suppose this method works since our mother kept her maiden name while both our grandmothers didn’t. Sometimes, albeit rarely, we will spell the familial relation word differently for each grandparent (grandpa/grandma vs grampa/gramma), but the pronunciation is the same for both sides of the family. When I am with an individual grandparent, I often omit the last name and just say “Grandma” or “Grandpa.”

Conversely, my sister and I usually refer to our uncles and aunt simply by their regular first names, with the words “uncle” and “aunt” attached only sometimes. I suppose this may seem strange to some people as well.

I am wondering what the most common strategies of naming these types of relatives are. I am also curious about  which methods and affectionate terms are more common throughout various parts of the Anglosphere.

Comment: In the UK, it's common for children to use different nicknames for the grandparents on either side - I had 'Granny and Grandpa' and 'Grandma' (pronounced 'granma'). I never knew my paternal grandfather, but had he lived I guess he might have been Grandad. My cousins' maternal grandmother was no relation to me, but I think of her as 'Granny [Surname]' because that was how _my_ Granny referred to her.

Comment: According to Name Nerd, the most popular nicknames for grandparents are Bubbe, Nana, Grandma, Granny, Gran, Gram, Grammy, Papa, Grandpa, Granda, Granddad, Gramps.  https://www.grandmagazine.com/2015/11/most-common-nicknames-for-grandparents/#:~:text=According%20to%20Name%20Nerd%2C%20the,%2C%20Granda%2C%20Granddad%2C%20Gramps.